# How do I find the intersection of row and column in Pandas or Openpyxl

Tags: pandas, openpyxl

so I am trying to create a attendance sheet here where we have the following data in excel

[image]

So my plan here is to write code in python using tkinter ,datetime module and pandas

Where the datetime module will get me todays date.
With the help of tkitners entry and todays date I want to find the intersection cell.

For example:
A and 11-01-2021 its intersection would be cell B2 and inside that cell on recording the attendance it will add "Present"

I am finding it really difficult to work with dates here.

Kindly help

Answer (score 1):

Convert file to DataFrame and select by name and date for scalar output, only necessary datetimes in columns names:

```
df = pd.read_excel(file, index_col=['Name'])
#if necessary
#df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns, dayfirst=True)

name = 'A'
today = pd.to_datetime('today').floor('D')
df.loc[name, today] = "Present"
```

Comment: This works fine, but just out of curiosity can this be done in openpyxl?

Comment: @ShernelMonteiro - Unfortunately never working with `openpyxl`, so cannot help yo uwith this.